# Resizing container view programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have auto layout and auto size classes disabled. I'm currently presenting a child view controller using the container view.

I can't access the container view as a property in my parent view controller, so I don't know how to programmatically set it's size?

I want to do something like this:

```
@interface ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic) NSContainerView *container;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.container setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height];
}
```

But it doesn't seem like there's a `NSContainerView` class or any public class to access it...

[image]

Comment: Did you add `IBOutlet` to that container? it added a `UIView` in your `UIViewcontroller` then you can set your `frame` accordingly

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the container view as an IBOutlet, then you can be able to resize it.